# Embed information cannot be pulled out from a variable

Tags: python, discord.py

[image][image]

I'm a rookie programmer student who is looking for a solution in this code.
I'm sure the solution is easier than I think, but it seems like I cannot find the problem.
"for name, value in polls: embed.add_field(name=name, value=value)" line of code seems like it cannot take out the information of my polls variable.
If i take out for name... line of code, then the function works but the embed has missing information.
If I put back this for name, value etc... line of code then the poll function wont even execute.
Thank you for your help

Sincerely

Charlie

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def poll (self, ctx, time: int, vote: int, title, *options):
    polls = [('\u200b'), '\n'.join([f'{self.emoji[index]} {options} \n' for index, option in enumerate(options)])]
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title,
                          description=f':stopwatch: Poll will end in **{time} minute**!',
                          colour=0xF0000)

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/{ctx.message.guild.id}/{ctx.message.guild.icon}.png')

    for name, value in polls:
        embed.add_field(name=name, value=value)

    message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

    for item in self.emoji[:len(options)]:
        await message.add_reaction(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be adapted in some ways.

What is `self.emoji[index]` supposed to give out?

I see what you are trying here, but you have to keep in mind that you want to count up with every "choice" you give in the poll.

The `thumbnail` of the embed can be set in an easier way. **Simply use the following:**

```py
embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon)
```

**Now let's begin with the magic.**

```py
for name, value in polls:
    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value)
```

Will not get you anywhere in connection with `polls = [(...)]` if I understood your code correctly. We can just use the `time` argument and add one argument ourselves.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
def to_emoji(c):
    base = 0x1f1e6 # Our base unicode emoji
    return chr(base + c)

# Your Class here

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def poll(self, ctx, time: int, *questions_and_choices: str):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=questions_and_choices[0],
                          colour=0xF0000)
    # The first argument will be the title
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon) # Get the guild icon
    if len(questions_and_choices) < 3: # Check that at least two choices are given
        return await ctx.send('**Please at least give one question and two choices**')
    choices = [(to_emoji(e), v) for e, v in enumerate(questions_and_choices[1:])]
    # Get the emojis that need to be added from our 'def'

    body = "\n".join(f"{key}: {c}" for key, c in choices) # Get the choices and "join" them into the embed with the specific key
    embed.description = f':stopwatch: Poll will end in **{time} minute**!\n\n {body}'
    poll = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    for emoji, _ in choices:
       await poll.add_reaction(emoji) # Add the reactions
```

**What we did**

- We built a function that returns the emoji and the next highest one(s)
- Enumerated over our given choices
- Assigned emojis to our choices

**Example screenshot:**

[image: Example screenshot]

If you want to use numbers instead of characters, just change it in our function.

Comment: Hello Dominik!
Yes I see I overtought my code a bit, but with your way I was able to understand the syntax a bit more and it worked out just fine eventually!
Thank you for the help a lot I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Sw4y If that helped you, do not forget to accept the answer so other people, who come across this error, can see a direct solution. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you added the error message, but I'm guessing you're getting something like `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. The reason is the following. Your `polls` variable contains only two strings. When you're doing something like

```
for a, b in polls:
    pass
```

, in the first iteration python is taking the first element of `polls` and tries to unpack it. Here's an example that works because the tuple can be unpacked into two variables:

```
polls = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
for i, j in polls:
    print(i, j)
```

But in your case, you're trying to unpack the `'\u200b'` string into two variables, which doesn't work. If you want to unpack `polls` into `name` and `value` you can do it like this: `name, value = polls`. But because there's really nothing to loop over, I'm not sure what you were trying to do.

Comment: There is no error message at all, thats the other problem.
The command in the discord app is just simply wont execute if I keep that line of code.
What I'm trying to do is a voting poll bot on discord and everything works fine except that there are no options in the poll .
The title, time, poll vote number and the reactions are all showing up except the options in the embed.
I have updated the thread so you can see what I am missing from the poll.
On the left picture is my poll and on the right its somebody elses and you can see that he has the option embeds in the poll.

Comment: Thank you for the help a lot!
With your help I was able to get the options part of the embed work, altough it was still not perfect, but from that point I was able to understand more and work with that information.